# PHP String replace Input element to span

Tags: php, regex

I have the below string with the multiple input elements

```
$str = '<input style="font-size:12px;width:100%" type="text" value="http://www.google.de/ggg">';
```

I want to convert this to

```
'<span style="font-size:12px;width:100%">http://www.google.de/ggg</span>';
```

How I can do it using PHP

Comment: please share with us what you have come up with yourself (code) and where you're stuck. To improve your question, don't hesitate to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for parse HTML code like:

```php
<?php
 $str = '<input style="font-size:12px;width:100%" type="text" value="http://www.google.de/ggg">';
 
 $dom = new DomDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($str);
 $input = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
 
 echo '<span style="' . $input->getAttributeNode('style')->value.'">' .
         $input->getAttributeNode('value')->value .
      '</span>';
```

[PHP fiddle](https://phpize.online/?phpses=447274ded53c0565298515de3716a967&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```php
$style = '';
$value = '';
$str = '<input style="font-size:12px;width:100%" type="text" value="http://www.google.de/ggg">';


$atr = preg_match_all('/\w+="[^"]*"/', $str, $matches);

if(!empty($matches[0])) {
    foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
        if (strpos($match, 'style') === 0) {
            $style = ' '.$match;
        }
        if (strpos($match, 'value') === 0) {
            $value = trim(substr($match, 6), '"');
        }
    }
}

echo '<span'.$style.'>'.$value.'</span>';
```

This would be more compact, but i leave it for clarity